# Number of toss to reject it is a fair coin

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

You toss the coin n times, and you have observed 60% of times, it is head.

How large n needs to be in order to achieve 95% confidence that it is not a fair coin?

=======

Attempt: Basically use Bionmial distribution, and but I have no idea how to take account of the 60% number into my calculation.

Comment: What is the sample mean and sample variance?

Comment: I think the sampled mean is 60%. If we simply use the confidence interval $CI = \text{mean} + z \frac{s}{\sqrt(n)}$, then we shall have the answer?

Comment: For how many tosses of a fair coin, the probability of getting heads $60\%$ of the times is less than $5\%$?

Comment: I think it comes to about 45 tosses.

Comment: @MathLover, I see you point, you seem to suggest that I should go with $\sum {n \choose x} (0.5)^k (0.5)^{n-k}$, but can I go with the confidence interval approach?

Comment: @MathLover, Can I not use:$ E=z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$ ?

Comment: But we do not have a sample mean (0.6 is not sample mean as it is not across multiple experiments). We do not have margin of error info from experiments if there was an experiment in the first place. I do not know how you would apply Confidence Interval here. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The question implies that you are to use the number of heads tossed as the test statistic for a [null-hypothesis significance test](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/hyp-test.pdf) of the hypothesis $\ H_0\ $ that the coin being tossed is fair, and find the smallest value of $\ n\ $ for which $\ 0.6n\ $ lies in a [critical region](https://internal.ncl.ac.uk/ask/numeracy-maths-statistics/statistics/hypothesis-testing/critical-region-and-confidence-interval.html) of significance $5\%$ (or, equivalently, outside the complementary confidence interval of $95\%$).

Unless you have a strong reason to believe that the coin could only be biassed towards heads (which is not suggested by anything in the wording of the question), you should be using a [two-tailed test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-_and_two-tailed_tests), for which the confidence interval would have the form $\ \left[\lfloor0.4n\rfloor+1, \lceil0.6n\rceil-1\right]\ $.  So if $\ N_h\ $ is the number of heads tossed, you have to find the smallest value of $\ n\ $ such that
\begin{align}
P\left(N_h\in \left[\lfloor0.4n\rfloor+1, \lceil0.6n\rceil-1\right]\big|H_0\right)&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=\lfloor0.4n\rfloor+1}^{\lceil0.6n\rceil-1}{n\choose k}\\
&\ge0.95
\end{align}
Under the null hypthesis, the mean of $\ N_h\ $ is $\ \frac{n}{2}\ $, and its variance is $\ \frac{n}{4}\ $, so $\ 0.6n\ $ is $\ 0.2\sqrt{n}\ $ standard deviations above the mean, and for large enough $\ n\ $ the probability that $\ N_h\ $ lies in the given interval can be well approximated by $\ \mathcal{N}(0,1)\big(0.2\sqrt{n}\big)-$$\mathcal{N}\big(0,1\big)(-0.2\sqrt{n})\ $, or, equivalently, by $\ 2\mathcal{N}(0,1)\big(0.2\sqrt{n}\big)-1\ $. So if $\ u\ $ is the (unique) positive number such that $\ \mathcal{N}(0,1)(u)=0.975\ $, then $\ n=\left(\frac{u}{0.2}\right)^2\ $ will be a reasonable approximation for the value you require.

Comment: Do you know if I can use the t-test, and instead of formulating the $n \choose k $?

Comment: To use a t-test you need to find a statistic which has a [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).  If $\ n\ $ is large enough for the normal approximation to the distribution of $\ N_h\ $ to be useable it  is possible to construct statistics which will be *approximately* Student's t-distributed.

Comment: The only way I know of doing this, however, would entail splitting your data into two or more sets and treating the numbers of heads in each set as independent (approximately) normal variates. There is really no point in doing this when you can just use the normal approximation directly, as explained in the last two sentences of my answer.